# How to join two fields of a same table in CI?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table named 'categories'. It's structure is like this:

```
id     parent_id       name
1      NULL            Electronics
2      NULL            Books
3      1               Mobile
4      2               Love Story
```

I want to join 'parent_id' with 'name' field. How can I join these two fields in codeigniter?

Comment: What does codeigniter/continuous integration have to do with this?

Comment: Why can't you use `concatenation`? Simply parent_id + name?

Comment: Provide an example of the output your looking for... I"m not sure if you're after `Electronics, Books, Electronics.Mobile, Books.Love Story `or something else... `Love Story.Books`... or 1.Mobile 2.Love Story, or what...  Incidentally this is a hierarchical query... how many levels and what RDBMS?

Comment: ci is automatically changed to continuous integration http://stackoverflow.com/tags/continuous-integration/synonyms

Answer (score 0):

This is known as self-join

```
SELECT a.name + '-' + b.name
FROM categories a
  INNER JOIN categories b
    ON a.id = b.parentid
```

Comment: @skonmai coul you check this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using CI's activerecord, take a look [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/135205/)

```
$this->db->select('*')
$this->db->from('categories c1')
$this->db->join('categories c2', 'c1.id = c2.parent_id');
```

Comment: I have 6 data in the table but it is fetching 12 data and it is only showing those data whose parent_id is not null, but I want to show all the data and instead of parent_id, I want to show the category name by joining it with id.